# Why should calling a currying function with non-complete args with underscore

Tags: scala, currying

According to ScalaByExample:

> A curried function definition def f (args1) ... (argsn) = E where n >
>   1 expands to
>
> def f (args1) ... (argsn−1) = { def g (argsn) = E ; g }
>
> Or, shorter, using an anonymous function:
>
> def f (args1) ... (argsn−1) = ( argsn ) => E

Uncurried version:

```
def f(x: Int): Int => Int = {
    y: Int => x * y
}                                             //> f: (x: Int)Int => Int

def f1 = f(10)                                //> f1: => Int => Int
f1(5)
```

Curried version:

```
def g(x: Int)(y: Int) = {
    x * y
}                                             //> g: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

def g1 = g(10) _                              //> g1: => Int => Int
g1(5)
```

The question is, Why curried required the underscore in line #5 in the second code snippet.

Comment: My guess is because otherwise the compiler wouldn't really know if you just forgot a parameter to your function or if you really meant it as a partial function. I'm sure there's a much more in depth answer though.

Comment: I read an answer like yours, but I still not fully convinced, the return type in this case will not be `Int`, instead it will be `Int => Int`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the explanation at Martin Odersky book: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html (search for "Why the trailing underscore").

In short this is because Scala is closer to Java in a lot of things, rather than functional languages where this is not required. This helps you to find out mistakes at compile time, if you forgot the missing argument.

If underscore was not required, the next code will compile:

```
println(g(10))
```

And this check helps you preventing such mistakes

There are some cases though, when such calls are obvious, and underscore is not required:

```
def g(x: Int)(y: Int) = {
    x * y
}

def d(f: Int => Int) {
  f(5)
}

d(g(10))   // No need to write d(g(2) _)

// Or any other way you can specify the correct type
val p: Int => Int = g(10)
```

Comment: println(g(10)) won't compile cause println has no overloading method that accepts Int => Int as parameter.

Comment: I meant that if `g(10) _` was not required, `println(g(10))` will compile and you won't notice a mistake. Sorry, it's not obvious from my answer, I will make a necessary corrections

Answer (score 1):

Something to note: in Scala, `def`'s are *methods*, not *functions*, at least, not directly. Methods are converted to functions by the compiler every time a method is used where a function would be required, but strictly speaking, a function would be created with `val` instead, like so:

```
val curry = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x * y
```

This allows you to apply arguments one at a time without having to add a trailing underscore. It functions identically to the code in your first snippet, but because it uses `val` and not `def`, `curry` cannot be written like

```
val curry(x: Int) = (y: Int) => x * y //Won't compile
```

So, when you want to write a *function* that behaves the way you want a curried function to behave, write it like I did in my first snippet. You can keep chaining parameters with `=>` as many times as you want (up to technical limits, but good luck hitting them).